# Liferay with LDAP and SSO

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, liferay-6

I tried using `portal-ext.properties` with values below.

Its still not allowing user to login.

I get **authentication failed error**.

When I check DB I do not see user imported.

**portal-ext.properties:**

> company.security.auth.type=screenName
>
> ldap.auth.enabled=true     ldap.auth.required=true
>
> ldap.auth.method=bind
>
> ldap.import.enabled=false      ldap.import.on.startup=false
>   ldap.import.method=user
>
> ldap.password.policy.enabled=false
>
> ldap.import.user.password.enabled=true
>
> ldap.import.user.password.autogenerated=false
>
> ldap.export.enabled=false
>
> ldap.base.provider.url.0=ldap://host:port
>
> ldap.base.dn.0=DC=companyName,DC=com
>
> ldap.security.principal.0=domainname/myusername
>
> ldap.security.credentials.0=mypassword
>
> ldap.auth.search.filter.0=(&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=@screen_name@))
>
> ldap.user.mappings.0=emailAddress=mail\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sn\npassword=userPassword\nscreenName=sAMAccountName\n
>
> ldap.import.user.search.filter.0=(objectClass=organizationalPerson)
>
> users.screen.name.allow.numeric=true
>
> users.screen.name.validator=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.DefaultScreenNameValidator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is define your own portal-ext.properties and overwrite properties for LDAP and if you need a SSO you can configure here a CAS too.
the [Liferay User Guide](http://www.liferay.com/es/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide), explain about use this [portal-ext.properties](http://www.liferay.com/es/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/liferay-home-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-15-en)

So look up all properties you [have for ldap](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#LDAP) and you have to overwrite:
and all properties you have [for CAS](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#CAS) and you have to overwrite:

After you create your portal-ext.properties put in \webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I will try your suggestion. Any idea which would be the best SSO to integrate with liferay? I was thinking of Opensso being widely used in the market,but CAS seems to be having great support with liferay.

Comment: I have used Liferay with CAS and the integration was ok and easy. You can have a look in this blog where explain every step:http://www.liferay.com/es/web/azar7k1s/blog/-/blogs/sso-via-cas-in-liferay

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect the situation after I tried above suggestion.Would you please help me understand whether I am missing some setting.

Comment: I do not remember the ldap are you using, but i see some properties maybe are wrong. I would write:ldap.auth.search.filter.0=(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=@screen_name@)), ldap.user.mappings use password=UnicodePwd, ldap.import.enabled=true, ldap.import.user.search.filter.0=(objectClass=user)

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have posted new question at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381101/liferay-with-ldap-and-sso".  Enabling "ldap.import.enabled" won't cause mass import of all the users? I want to import users on demand.

Comment: If you want only on demand the property ldap.import.enabled must be false and you have to set the LDAP authentication.